# How to select an asymptotic curve given an estimate of its limit and a sample of points

Tags: regression, predictive-models, modeling, econometrics, nonparametric

I am working with economic models which measure the value of information associated with medical research.

**What I know about the functional form:**
The amount of information generated by a hypothetical medical trial begins at zero for a trial with zero sample size ($n=0$) and increases with sample size until it reaches a maximum. This maximum represents the value of information from an infinitely sized trial ($n=\infty$).

**The problem and what I want to do:** For policy decision making it is useful to know the value of information ($\nu$) for all plausible sample sizes ($n$) but each evaluation of them model takes a long time to run i.e. estimating a particular point ($\hat\nu\; for \;n=i$) on the asymptotic curve eats a lot of computation time. I want to learn the shape of the curve without running an infinite number of model evaluations.

**What data I have:** I have an estimate of the asymptotic limit for the curve $\hat\theta$ which is estimated with uncertainty using a spline model. I also have a set of estimates of $\nu$ at various values of $n$;.

**My current guess:** If I assume that the curve is increasing at a constant rate and the errors are homoskedastic then it is possible to transform the values of $\hat\nu$ into a linear form using $\hat\theta$ and then run an OLS and re-transform. However this is not general enough as a lot of the time this does not hold. Also possible to do this for a two parameter model which allows increase at an increasing or decreasing rate. This is analogous to a survival model and one line of attack could be to keep adding parameters to this model.

What would be ideal would be some way to select from the set of all possible concave asymptotic curves with an origin at zero, but my math is not up to that!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the economic model itself, one possibility is to first calibrate a [surrogate model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_model) (using a [design of computational experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_experiment#Design_of_computer_experiments) approach, e.g. [DACE](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/projects/dace/)). This would give a cheap way to get approximate model results quickly, which you could then use in your VOI calculations. This type of approach is useful if e.g. VOI is a post-processing of several model outputs, and the model has many more inputs than just sample size as input.

If the model is literally VOI[n], but just slow to compute, then the "design of experiments approach" essentially reduces to adaptive sampling. In that case you could for example just choose new $n$ values to evaluate based on where your spline has high curvature. This would me more akin to [adaptive mesh refinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_mesh_refinement).

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you can fit this with a model of value like

$$E[v \vert n]=\alpha + \beta \cdot \frac{1}{n}$$

The parameter $\alpha>0$ will give you the value asymptote. This functional form also has the benefit that the value only becomes positive only above some threshold $n^*$, which might be reasonable if there is some sort of fixed cost.

Comment: Thank you for the response Dimitriy. Two questions, first, wouldn't this throw away the information I have about the asymptote ($\hat a$)? Second , would this impose a constant rate of change in $\nu$ with respect to $n$?  Or might it be possible to estimate $\beta$ as a vector using a non-parametric method to allow for non-linearities ?

Comment: @Dai_thai First, if you have some information about $\hat \alpha$, you can subtract it from each $\nu_i$ before fitting my simple model without an intercept. I am not sure what the benefit of imposing that constraint would be since I don't follow all the details of your set up. Second, the marginal effect of $n$ from the simple model would be $-\beta \cdot \frac{1}{n^2}$, which would be positive but declining to zero with $n$, assuming that $\beta<0$. The marginal effect is not constant and nonlinear by construction, though restricted to be smooth.